# Excel get number of a number

Tags: excel

> I would like to know how do i get a digit of one number in another
>   cell.
>
> Here it is a example:
>
> On cell A3 i have the number 101 and i would like to know how do i put
>   on the cell B3 the number 1, on C3 the number 0 and on D3 the number
>   1.

"Just like on this file:"
[Link](https://mega.co.nz/#!swRiTZZS!ZzEzt_fUkzxdcEQ5ha1KGFCtXgcaPE7Yt2JSiLDrwRE)

Note:This would be used to work with 1024 digits.
And im using Office 2013.

Answer (score 2):

Use this formula:

```
=MID($A3,COLUMN()-1,1)
```

Note: if you want to store your huge 1024 digits as text (and you will have to because Excel allows only 15 digits of precision for decimal numbers) you should put apostrophe before your values like:

```
'100101010101001110101100110
```

Comment: What `doesn't work`? It's working. Downloaded your file, tested the above formula, and it's working fine. Copy and paste to `B3` and drag to the right as far as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Put this formula in cell B3 and then copy right (highlight cells to the right and press Ctrl+R):

```
=MID(TEXT($A3,"0"),COLUMN()-1,1)
```

Comment: Technically there is no need to convert the string to text, AFAIK.

Comment: Did u tryed on the file that i shared? Becouse its not working with me.

Comment: @BoxEdition: The link is no longer available... why is that?

Comment: Hmmm - your spreadsheet didn't exactly bring a lot to the party. I copied my formula into your spreadsheet and it works fine. I don't have Office 2013 but I can't believe that would make much difference. Could you not just say what the error is - I think that would be more help.